# Contradicting exception specifications for same method in different interfaces

Tags: java, exception

In the following code:

```
class MyException extends Exception{}

interface Bread
{
    public void eat() throws MyException;
}

interface Fringe 
{
    public void eat() throws RuntimeException;
}

public class Test implements Fringe , Bread // #5
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Fringe best = new Test(); // #1
        best.eat();// #2
    }

    public void eat() throws RuntimeException // #3
    {
        System.out.println("Test");
        throw new RuntimeException(); // #4
    }
}
```

`MyException` is not a `RuntimeException`. Why we can declare `Test.eat()` as throwing a `RuntimeException` but not a general `Exception`?

Comment: Are you sure this is the corrent code? MyException isn't actually thrown anywhere here.

Answer (score 4):

This is because in the overriding method, you can only throw exceptions below or equal to the exception defined in your contract. So, `eat()` can throw `MyException` and its subclasses but not anything above `MyException` which is what `Exception` is. Runtime exceptions are not a part of this rule and you can freely throw them since they are not "checked".

This is because let's say I'm using the `Bread` interface to access the instance of `Test` class. If I call the `eat()` method, I can "check" for `MyException` since it's part of the contract but if the underlying implementation decides to throw a "higher" exception, it won't be caught within my `MyException` catch block thus violating the contract. Have a look at the below code for an example:

```
Bread b = new Test();
try {
  // if this throws Exception, it won't be caught in the catch block
  // thereby violating contract
  b.eat(); 
} catch (MyException e) {
  e.printStacktrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two points:

- You cannot declare it to throw `Exception`, because it would then throw a more general exception than what the `eat()` method in the `Bread` interface specifies. A method inherited from a superclass or interface cannot throw more general exceptions than what is specified in the superclass or interface.
- You can declare it to throw `RuntimeException` because methods can always throw unchecked exceptions, whether you specify them in a `throws` clause or not. (So specifying that it can throw `RuntimeException` is redundant).

To explain the reason for the rule I mentioned in the first point: Suppose you do this:

```
// Allowed because Test implements Bread
Bread obj = new Test();
```

If you now call `obj.eat()`, the compiler needs to check if you correctly handle all checked exceptions that might happen in that call. It does this by looking at the type of the variable `obj`, which is `Bread`. The `Bread` interface specifies that `eat()` can throw `MyException` (and implicitly, subclasses of `MyException`).

If your `Test.eat()` method were allowed to throw a more general kind of checked exception, such as `Exception`, then the compiler cannot check by just looking at the type of `obj` that you handle all checked exceptions correctly.

To prevent this problem, the rule is that an overridden method is not allowed to throw more general exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

> An overriding method can only throw those exceptions which satisfy **IS-A** relationship with the exception thrown in overriden method.

If you try to throw `Exception` in your class while interface throws `MyException` ... compiler sees if following statement is true:

*Exception IS-A MyException* -- and it's false, you know. so compiler rejects it.

> Hence you can throw only a more-specific exception from a method in sub-class.

for you question about RunTime Exception:

> For throwing RunTime exception, it is equivalent to as if you've not written it explicitly. so compiler ignores it. because even if you don't mention it a method can throw exception at Runtime.